# Formula Error: Syntax error. Extra ','

Tags: formula, custom-field, formula-field

I am trying to write a formula for opportunities but I keep getting the following error

Error: Syntax error. Extra ','

Here is my formula

```
    IF 
    (TODAY() > CloseDate && TEXT(StageName)='Donation Likely')
    || 
    (TODAY() > CloseDate && TEXT(StageName)='Donation Prospecting'),"Past              
    Due","Expecting")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The start Bracket `(` of `IF` is missing. Try this one:-

```
IF(
     (TODAY() > CloseDate && TEXT(StageName)='Donation Likely')
     || 
     (TODAY() > CloseDate && TEXT(StageName)='Donation Prospecting'),
     "Past Due",
     "Expecting"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your formula is that `Past Due` status is going to be shown **ONLY** when `CloseDate` is in the past **AND** StageName is 'Donation Likely' or 'Donation Prospecting'. The following formula would make much more sense:

```
IF(
 TODAY() > CloseDate,
 'Past Due',
 IF( TEXT(StageName) = 'Donation Likely')
  || 
  TEXT(StageName) = 'Donation Prospecting'),
  'Expecting',
  'Not_So_Likely_Status'
 )
)
```